# Repeating function while incrementing [i] within

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, increment

I'm trying to call **repeatThis** n times while incrementing **myArr[i]** on each iteration. Putting a loop inside the function before the last bracket will blow up the browser call stack. Also can't put a function within a loop without getting errors.

Functionally, I want it to flip through jpegs so it looks like a movie.

```
 function repeatThis () {
        $(myArr[i]).fadeIn(100, function(){
            $(myArr[i]).fadeOut(100, function(){
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use each!! So the syntax looks like

```
$.each(myArr, function( index, value ) {
  $(myArr[index]).fadeIn(100, function(){
    $(myArr[index]).fadeOut(100, function(){
  });
});
```

This should work, unless there is something else in your code messing up your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing i as a function parameter:

```
function repeatThis(i) {
    ...
})(i);
```